# What answer is expected for a high-schooler on that black hole question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, education

**EDIT: I asked my son to ask his physics teacher about that question. I made an answer for completeness with what she said but will accept the escape velocity based one**

My son is in high school (France, 1<sup>ère</sup> = 11th grade) and they work on gravitational fields. The concept of the field is loosely introduced ("there is a field", basically - without explaining what a field is and what it is used for) and they concentrate on the norm of the gravitational force $F = G m_1 m_2 r^{-2}$.

One of the exercises he was doing (outside of homework, he usually goes through all the exercises in his book), noted with two stars (out of three) is an exercise of

- understanding an article (from a popular scientific journal)
- make some calculations
- and the problematic question I want to address

The article (I provide the whole exercise at the end, it is in French) mentions the radiative and gravitational forces in a star, the fact that depending on the mass the star may become a dwarf star or a supernova and then a black hole (depending on its mass).

The a), b) and c) questions were simple (either text understanding or basic calculation of $F$), he was surprised by the last one (emphasis mine)

> A black hole is a celestial object which gravitational field is so intense that it prevents any form of matter from escaping. **Justify this affirmation.**

What is the kind of justification that is expected? (I know about the event horizon, Schwarzschild radius and other related concepts but this is way beyond their level)

**The core of my question is: is there a physical interpretation of this claim that can be derived from the information in the article?**

The exercise in French:

[image]

*Source: "Déclic Phisique-Chimie 1<sup>ère</sup>spé", Hachette Education, 2019*

Comment: If my french serves me right (which might not), even I don't see how such an answer can be extrapolated from the given article which just explains how the collapse of a star changes based on its mass and not how a black hole behaves.

Comment: @DavideMorgante well there is a chapter before the article.

Comment: @Alchimista: which chapter are you referring to? I do not have the book with me right now but the topic is gravitational forces (and electrostatic), this is the only place they discuss black holes.

Comment: @WoJ see the answer by Francesco Citterio. Is the only reasonable answer that the author of the book shall expect.

Comment: @Alchimista: yes, I accepted it, though after getting the "official answer" these questions are truly disappointing (the teachers are great, though - they just must deal with the curriculum). I added it to the answers for completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question talks about mass (and not light) maybe the expected answer regards excape velocity, which for a mass big enough in a radius small enough would exeed the speed of light. (So relativity is involved, but with a quite notorius fact).
Now excape velocity is a High School topic I think...

Comment: Thanks. Escape velocity is not a topic in high school (yes, I am disappointed as well). They did not even really discuss $F=ma$. Besides, without getting into relativity, the mere existence of a black hole (which for them is just a dense object with a large pass) does not explain that **no** matter can escape. I am not trying to argue with your answer - I am just trying to imagine what the correct answer could be with all your inputs.

Comment: I agree with you, my answer was about guessing what a high school book would expect

Answer (score 1):

After asking my son to ask the question to his physics teacher, her response was that the question does not make much sense with what they learnt so far and that the only thing they could try is to check the order of magnitude of the force and realize that it is "large".

When I compare what they learn to what I had in high school (same profile, same school) I am sad to see how boring their curriculum is today.

Comment: At my time no way to have exotic stuff and fancy pictures. But In my opinion the exercise proposed it is not that bad, especially as an extra. Please check if they do not explain things such as escape velocity (I mean the book, not the teacher). If not then the question makes no sense. If yes, then something is "wrong" with the curriculum or the teacher. Sorry but I do insist that is not only the excerpt that counts.

Comment: @Alchimista: I understand what you mean. I just checked the book (and my son) and as I thought they just started some vague concept of field (lots of handwaving), then the Newton and Coulomb law. That's all. The exercise until the last point is good (understanding of a text, then some practical use of the laws). It is just that last point that baffles me. I closely follow my children work so I would not have missed something like escape velocity :)

Comment: no doubts. Somehow I like to discuss about school.

Answer (score 0):

He must be aware that nothing travels faster than speed of light  $V_C$  and what is escape velocity $V_E$  . Then black hole is  body for which the escape velocity is greater than speed of light i.e $$V_E>=V_C$$ This would mean if anything wants to escape the gravitational pull of black hole it would have to be thrown at speed greater than speed of light.

But do you think rockets leaving earth ever travel at escape velocity for Earth? This answer would satisfy him if doesn't think about this point.